# Убрать объекты из массива не меняя исходный массив

Tags: javascript

Подобный вопрос уже есть, НО в данной задаче необходимо:
Убрать из массива все объекты с типом "additional", а для "basic" очки уменьшить в двое.

И самое главное условие:
**Cоздать новый массив, оставляя исходные данные неизменными**

То есть исходный массив **myLesson** менять нельзя.

```
const myLesson = [
    {lesson: 1, type: 'basic', points: 2},
    {lesson: 2, type: 'additional', points: 4},
    {lesson: 3, type: 'basic', points: 6},
    {lesson: 4, type: 'additional', points: 3},
    {lesson: 5, type: 'basic', points: 4},
    {lesson: 6, type: 'basic', points: 2},
    {lesson: 7, type: 'additional', points: 2},
    {lesson: 8, type: 'basic', points: 6},
    {lesson: 9, type: 'basic', points: 4},
    {lesson: 10, type: 'basic', points: 6},
    {lesson: 11, type: 'additional', points: 5}, 
    {lesson: 12, type: 'basic', points: 2}, 
    {lesson: 13, type: 'additional', points: 2}, 
    {lesson: 14, type: 'basic', points: 4},
    {lesson: 15, type: 'additional', points: 1},
    {lesson: 16, type: 'additional', points: 7},
];
```

Пытался по всякому

Например так:

```
let array = myLesson.slice().filter(item => item.type !== 'additional')
    .map(item => item.points /= 2);
```

Или так:

```
const array = [...myLesson];
const array2 = array.filter((item) => item.type !== 'additional')
    .map(item => item.points /= 2);
```

Попыток было много, но все они ни к чему не привели.
В исходном массиве **myLesson** всё равно меняется значение **points**

Помогите, люди добрые, идей у меня нет, те что были - не работают как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов `slice` не нужен, `filter` уже конструирует новый список.

В приведенной попытке map преобразует массив объектов в массив чисел, так как оператор присваивания с делением внезапно возвращает результат операции. А надо конструировать новый объект из старого, вот так.

```
myLesson
    .filter(item => item.type !== 'additional')
    .map(item => ({...item, points: item.points/2}));
```

Сначала берем `item` как есть и модифицируем нужное поле нужным образом.

Comment: Спасибо большое за быстрый и четкий ответ с хорошим объяснением!
Теперь понял свою ошибку